# In c#.net.im getting invalid column name error but i have given a correct column name,how can i rectify this error

Tags: c#

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=INBLR-RK\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbo.EMployee;Integrated Security=True");
      conn.Open();
      SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("INSERT INTO empnew Values (" + textBox1.Text + ", '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "'," + textBox5.Text + ",'" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "'," + textBox9.Text + ")", conn);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet("empnew");
      da.Fill(ds);
      conn.Close();
  }
```

Comment: There is also an sql exception at da.fill(ds)

Comment: Do you have a specific question about the code you've posted? Your title isn't very precise.

Comment: I don't see any column names specified, just a whole bunch of SQL injection.

Comment: why don't you use SqlParamters? passing values in query like this prone to SQL injection...

Comment: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the columns you want to insert into (`INSERT INTO dbo.empnew(col1, col2, ..., colN) .....`)! Otherwise, you always have to provide values for all columns (and if the table changes, your INSERT might suddenly **not work** anymore!)

Comment: What exceptions are you getting?

Answer (score 5):

You have several issues:

1. You are calling `DataAdapter.Fill` and according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxkb3c3d.aspx) (read the Remarks section) it should be used to SELECT or ADD rows to a dataset but it won't add any records to the database; as you are intending.
2. Your code is prone to SQL Injection Attacks. You should never concatenate strings to form a Sql Statement. Use Prepared Statements instead; something like this:

   ```
   using(SqlConnection  connection = new SqlConnection("ConnString"))
   {
      connection.Open();
      SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("insert into table_name(col_name) values (@value)",connection);
      comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value",theValue);
      comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
   ```
3. You claim that you are specifying column names; but **you aren't**.